# Getting Raw XML From SOAPBody in Java (for a camel flow?)

Tags: java, soap, apache-camel

How do I get the raw xml from SOAPBody? Perhaps some util function that will just give me the Body xml (not body text). I don't want to reinvent code to walk through every node/child - it may already be there in some util?

Camel flow has a dataconverter  "soapjxb", but I don't have a need to map/unmarshal to java objects.

Why do I need that?: Cleanup operation

One of the client app (that I'm trying to integrate using ApacheCamel), is putting an xml message to my mq, the message is embedded within a soap envelope ("unnecessary noise"), I can't change the client-app. I have to just discard the soap envelope and take the xml within the soap-body and post it to another jmsqueue.

PS:
I know how to get raw xml from SOAPMessage as mentioned here: [Getting Raw XML From SOAPMessage in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522395/getting-raw-xml-from-soapmessage-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

if you have the SOAPEnvelope in XML, then just use [xpath](http://camel.apache.org/xpath.html) to isolate the XML you want and send it on its way...

```
.setBody(xpath("//SOAPBody"))...
```

Comment: Tried xml equivalent of the above:
 <transacted ref="txnPolicyPROP-REQD" />
 <pipeline>
 <setBody><xpath>//SOAPBody</xpath></setBody>
 <bean ref="preProcessor" method="populateCorrelationId" />
 <bean ref="preProcessor" method="stampMsgWithErfRequestId" >
 <to uri ...>
Error I got:
 On delivery attempt: 5 caught: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter available to convert from type: org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.DTMNodeList to the required type: org.w3c.dom.Document with value org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.DTMNodeList@1ace672

Answer (score -1):

Use xslt to remove the namespaces and treat as normal xml.

&ltxsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"&gt  &ltxsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" /&gt&ltxsl:template match="*"&gt&ltxsl:element name="{local-name()}"&gt&ltxsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" /&gt&lt/xsl:element&gt&lt/xsl:template&gt&ltxsl:template match="@*"&gt     &ltxsl:attribute name="{local-name()}"&gt &ltxsl:value-of select="." /&gt&lt/xsl:attribute&gt&lt/xsl:template&gt&ltxsl:template match="text() | comment() | processing-instruction()"&gt &ltxsl:copy /&gt &lt/xsl:template&gt&lt/xsl:stylesheet&gt

replace &gt with greater than and &lt with less than ans save as xslt and use for tranformation to remove soap namespaces.