# How to convert byte array of a SOAP message to raw XML in Java

Tags: java, xml, dom, soap, jdom

I am working on a web service, services talk to each other with SOAPMessage (SOAP XML). SOAPMessage enters my method as a byte array

> `public void process(byte xmlByteArray[]){
>   ...
>   .....
>   }`

what i need is to convert this byte array to raw XML so that i can process it with JDOM.

do you know any solution for this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/522395/getting-raw-xml-from-soapmessage-in-java

Comment: i have seen that. i guess there is one more step here : converting byte array to soap message.

Comment: What exactly is your desired output format of the method?

Comment: JDOM Document is ideal.

Comment: love you down voters. leave a comment at least :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
Document document = builder.build(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlByteArray));
```

See http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/XML/ReadanXMLdocumentusingJDOM.htm

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static Document byteArrayToDocument( final byte[] byteArray ) throws IOException, SAXException,
        ParserConfigurationException
{
     final DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
     final DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
     return builder.parse( new ByteArrayInputStream( byteArray ) );
}
```

Comment: it may work but the return type of your method is org.w3c.dom.Document and not JDOM.Document.

Comment: i guess i can convert it to string and re-convert it back

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do this in [VTD-XML](http://vtd-xml.sf.net)

import com.ximpleware.*;

```
public class readBytes{

    public static void main(String[] s} throws VTDException{
        VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
        //get XML Byte array here
        vg.setDoc(xmlByteArray);
        vg.parse();
        VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
    }
}
```