# Apache CXF print customized SOAPEnvelope

Tags: cxf, jax-ws

We are consuming a `JAX-WS` webservice through our web application running on TomEE Plus. It uses `Apache CXF` implementation to interact with the webservice.

We wanted to log the requests and response XMLs that are sent and received as part of the webservice calls. There are numerous examples of that which helps us to log the **complete** request and response why we use `Apache CXF`.

However, we have a situation where the complete request XML should not be logged since there are some sensitive information in that. We are modifying the `SOAPEnvelope` to remove the sensitive information in the `SOAPHandler` that takes care of logging them.

To do the printing, are there any libraries available that help us to print the complete XML data?

In IBM WebSphere, the JAX-WS implementation (not sure which one it was) could print the `SOAPEnvelope` just by using the `toString()` method. Where as the CXF returns `null` while trying the `toString()` of `SOAPEnvelope`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                SOAPMessage message = messageContext.getMessage();
                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
                transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
                transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
                transformer.transform(new DOMSource(message.getSOAPPart()), new StreamResult(sw));
                logger.info(sw.toString());
```

Based on the answers from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522395/getting-raw-xml-from-soapmessage-in-java)