# Unable to view reply in SOAP call

Tags: java, soap

I'm currently working on a custom SOAP call to a specific domain beyond my control. I know the SOAP call fails but I cannot seem to grab the returned (wrong)value.

Right now I'm using the code below:

```
                    Document document = convertStringToDocument(this.MeldingString);
                // System.out.println(document);
                SOAPConnectionFactory myFct = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
                MessageFactory myMsgFct = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL);
                SOAPMessage message = myMsgFct.createMessage();
                SOAPConnection myCon = myFct.createConnection();

                // Adding parts
                SOAPPart mySPart = message.getSOAPPart();
                SOAPEnvelope myEnvp = mySPart.getEnvelope();

                // Escape the password for usage in header
                String escpwd = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(this.Password);

                // Header
                MimeHeaders headers = message.getMimeHeaders();
                headers.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8");
                headers.setHeader("Authorization", this.Username + ":" + escpwd);

                // Body
                SOAPBody body = myEnvp.getBody();
                body.addDocument(document);

                // Sending
                Core.getLogger("GetResultSOAPmsg").trace("Started");
                URL endPt = new URL(
                        "URL-TO-MY-SERVICE");
                System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
                try {
                    SOAPMessage reply = myCon.call(message, endPt); "UTF-8");

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

This yields the following error which is very common al throughout SO:

```
SEVERE: SAAJ0537: Invalid Content-Type. Could be an error message instead of a SOAP message
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?
```

Now I have read most of these topics already and they explain how this problem is usually solved (namespaces, escaping URL, etc.) but I cannot seem to figure out what is wrong in my case. This is a private service and the other side is unfortunately unable to assist me in this case. The error could be anything from wrong certificates to misspelling the URL.

Therefore I would like to actually SEE onscreen what the actual reply is that was received when making the call. This is going to help me (assuming it's something like a 503, 404 or other page). Regardless of what I do and where I set my breakpoints, there is no information on Reply. It makes somewhat sense since it was unable to create said object but the entire message seems to be discarded.

**In what way will I be able to see what the actual reply was to my call before it is discarded?**

Comment: You might try to learn the raw content either from the soap message or the soap part as suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522395/getting-raw-xml-from-soapmessage-in-java)

Comment: [This blog post](https://aykutakin.wordpress.com/2014/03/20/logging-soap-web-service-request-and-response/) suggest to use a custom handler for logging raw SOAP requests and responses

Comment: @RomanVottner: Thanks for the replies. I will look into these posts.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a problem with your header

```
headers.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8");
```

try something like

```
headers.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml;charset=UTF-8");
```

or

```
headers.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
```

depending on the content type that the content type accepted by the service

Comment: Hi Piaget. Perhaps I'm completely mistaken but I don't see how that should be solving my issue. I know for a fact that the expected response is not the same as the actual response (I expect a SOAP message, but instead get plain HTML). I was wondering when I need to intervene in order to actually see the reply output (in this case the HTML). Even if the headers are wrong, there is likely something else wrong as well. I do appreciate the effort you took to write this answer.